# Overwrite a Function in a class called by another class

Tags: php, class, oop

For a given a library like this:

```
class boss {
    private $sub;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->sub = new subclass();
    }
}

class subclass {

    public function dofoo() {
        echo 'subclass';
    }
}
```

Due to reasons I can not modify anything inside the library.

```
class newboss extends boss {
    public function __construct() {
        // do stuff
        parent::__construct();
    }
    // extend some other boss methods

    function dofoo() {
        echo 'newboss - ';
        parent::dofoo();
    }
}

$x = new newboss;
$x->dofoo();
```

Extending functions in `newboss` works straight forward as expected. I need to extend the `subclass`, especially `subclass->dofoo()`, so that the output will be `newboss - subclass` instead of `newboss`.
Sure, calling `parent::dofoo()` will never work because I'm not extending `subclass` but I hope for any good advices / ideas to solve the problem.

Thank you very much.

### update

To be a little bit cleare, class boss calls `subclass()` and stores it in `private $sub` for usage. There are multiple calls like `$this->sub->dofoo()`in boss which also needs to be able to use my extended version.

Comment: Since you can't modify the library and `subclass` does not extend `boss`, I don't believe there is a way to do what you want. Those two classes are not related.

Comment: This is what I think too, but I still hope there is a (maybe hacky way) around...

Comment: @smtw If PHP supported multiple inheritance perhaps, but it [doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815568/is-there-any-way-to-achieve-multiple-inheritance-in-php).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you need to extend the subclass, then only use a subclass instance (public or private) as the same in boss.
The class boss use **delegation** and is an alternative to inheritance :

```
class newboss extends boss {
    public $sub;
    public function __construct() {
        // do stuff
        parent::__construct();
        $this->sub = new subclass();
    }
    // extend some other boss methods

    function dofoo() {
        echo 'newboss - ';
        $this->sub->dofoo();
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the idea and will further investigate. On a quick test it wasn't working. Especially because `subclass()` is called in `boss` with several parameters, like `$this->sub = new subclass($this, $this->x ...);`.

Comment: There's no need to create `public` properties here.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the [Facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) pattern and add methods as required:

```
class Facade
{
    $a = new newboss;
    $b = new subclass;

    function dofoo() {
        echo 'newboss - ';
        $b->dofoo();
    }
}
```

Client code:

```
$x = new Facade;
$x->dofoo();
```

Comment: Looks interesting, but does this not break it? Because class `boss` calls `subclass()` and stores it in `private $sub` for usage. There are multiple calls like `$this->sub->dofoo()`in `boss` which then wold ignore my extended `dofoo(). Or am I wrong?

Comment: `boss` would not break because it doesn't know anything about the new `Facade` class. But it also wouldn't be able to call your new `dofoo` method for the same reason.

Comment: This example doesn't even compile.